# Kinvey with admob on android

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-multidex, kinvey

Kinvey runs fine by itself but when I include

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'

in the gradle dependencies

I get the following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

When I ad the kinvey jars to the gradle

Now I have tried researching this problem and tried multidexing and increasing the max heapsize which resulted in the following error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kinvey.java.core.KinveyClientRequestInitializer
                                                                                 at com.kinvey.android.Client$Builder.(Client.java:574)

Oddly enough the issue only comes up when I include the ads api(WHICH MUST BE INCLUDED ALONG WITH KINVEY)

I am not sure how to resolve this problem or if this problem is related to the size of the dex file or if it is a redundant package I would appreciate help in this matter and thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I added

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(base);
}
```

to my launcher class

Answer (score 0):

Try adding multiDexEnabled true to your app build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: I tried that and got the error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kinvey.java.core.KinveyClientRequestInitializer
                                                                                 at com.kinvey.android.Client$Builder.<init>(Client.java:573)

When I try to build the client.  I also tried max heap size it did not work either.  

I think using multidexing is not allowing the all the kinvey methods to be together so it can't function.  

Is their somthing I'm doing wroung or is their a way to fix this?